# Is there a integer that makes $e^{\pi\sqrt{n}}$ closer to an integer than 163?

Tags: number-theory, approximation, pi

$e^{π\sqrt{163}}$ is almost an integer about $262537412640768744$.

Let $\delta = -\log_{10}{\left|[x] -x\right|}$, where $[x]$ means round $x$.

$\delta(e^{π\sqrt{163}}) \approx 12.125$, I searched for integers less than one million and did not find a larger one.

\begin{array}{l|l}
 n & \delta \\
 \hline
 163 & 12.12498077672643 \\
 652 & 9.785848809982161 \\
 1467 & 8.005405448223059 \\
 58 & 6.750100588198867 \\
 2608 & 6.510795060473921 \\
 478233 & 6.336824235216279 \\
 881967 & 6.179002616555315 \\
 880111 & 6.049818696834100 \\
 67 & 5.873691345976712 \\
 160874 & 5.779904075261147 \\
 895056 & 5.744074506024677 \\
 22905 & 5.609682778906657 \\
 674707 & 5.608982629715706 \\
 95041 & 5.548433878234871 \\
 486396 & 5.540950430696813 \\
 343732 & 5.507752498953491 \\
 357711 & 5.478776357709137 \\
 54295 & 5.365357632965891 \\
 613399 & 5.357752793344790 \\
 470884 & 5.281604204081554 \\
\end{array}

$163$ is the biggest in class number 1.

$652 = 4 \times 163$, so worse than $163$.

$1467 = 9 \times 163$, so worse than $163$.

$58 = 232/4$, where $232$ is class number 2.

---

Then I searched in primes, but seems worse.

\begin{array}{l|l}
 n & \delta \\
 \hline
 163 & 12.12498077672643 \\
 67 & 5.873691345976712 \\
 2259143 & 5.594638040601917 \\
 1003957 & 5.559376877231691 \\
 2785649 & 5.506950408472213 \\
 3227963 & 5.506387694695041 \\
 2471017 & 5.031440103309939 \\
 33563 & 4.912614873386113 \\
 719 & 4.894475032853204 \\
 28201 & 4.841231735669607 \\
\end{array}

---

So, is there a integer that makes $e^{\pi\sqrt{n}}$ closer to an integer than 163?

Comment: 163 is as good as it gets.  Research Heegner numbers for more details.

Comment: You are aware that we care of $j(i\sqrt{n})$ not $e^{\pi \sqrt{n}}$ ? Both the $\tau$ such that $j(\tau) \in \Bbb{Z}$ and the values of $j(i \sqrt{n})$ are well studied subject and if something can be said about your problem it will be somewhere in the litterature. The difficulty is that the euclidean norm is meaningful only for quadratic imaginary number fields (ie. class number one in which case $j(i\sqrt{n}) \in \Bbb{Z}$).

Comment: Do we have a proof that $163$ is actually the champion ? Or is it just very hard to beat ?

Comment: Assuming that the distribution of $\{\operatorname{frac}(\exp \pi \sqrt{n}) : 1 \leq n \leq N\}$ converges to a uniform distribution (on $[0, 1)$) as $N \to \infty$, asymptotically just $1$ number in $10^{\delta(\exp (\pi \sqrt{n})) -\log_{10}2} \approx 10^{11.82}$ to have $\delta(n) > \delta(\exp (\pi \sqrt{163}))$, so we'd expect the odds for finding one in a sample of just $1$ million to be $\approx 10^{-5.82}$.

Comment: In a sample size of $1$ million, by the way, we'd expect to find one $n$ with $\delta(n) > \log_{10}(2 \cdot 10^6) = 6 + \log_{10} 2 \approx 6.30$, and we see that among the first million there are several $n$ that beat this figure by a wide margin, but four are $163 m^2$, $m = 1, \ldots, 4$, and the other two have $\delta(n) < 6.8$.

Comment: I've protected this question due to the recent influx of users answering.